# RSQLite dbGetQuery with input from Data Frame

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have a database called "db" with a table called "company" which has a column named "name".

I am trying to look up a company name in db using the following query:

```
dbGetQuery(db, 'SELECT name,registered_address FROM company WHERE  LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER("%APPLE%")')
```

This give me the following correct result:

```
  name             
1 Apple
```

My problem is that I have a bunch of companies to look up and their names are in the following data frame

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("apple", "microsoft","facebook"))
```

I have tried the following method to get the company name from my df and insert it into the query:

```
sqlcomp <- paste0("'SELECT name, ","registered_address FROM company WHERE  LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(",'"', df[1,1],'"', ")'")

dbGetQuery(db,sqlcomp)
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
tinyformat: Too many conversion specifiers in format string
```

I've tried several other methods but I cannot get it to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this code should work

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("apple", "microsoft","facebook"))
comparer <- paste(paste0(" LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%",df[,1],"%')"),collapse=" OR ")

sqlcomp <- sprintf("SELECT name, registered_address FROM company WHERE %s",comparer)
dbGetQuery(db,sqlcomp)
```

Hope this helps you move on.

Please vote my solution if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste` to paste in *data* into a query is generally a bad idea, due to SQL injection (whether truly injection or just accidental spoiling of the query). It's also better to keep the query free of "raw data" because DBMSes tend to optimize a query once and reuse that optimized query every time it sees the same query; if you encode data in it, it's a new query each time, so the optimization is defeated.

It's generally better to use *parameterized* queries; see https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries.

For you, I suggest the following:

```r
df <- data.frame(names = c("apple", "microsoft","facebook"))
qmarks <- paste(rep("?", nrow(df)), collapse = ",")
qmarks
# [1] "?,?,?"
dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select name, registered_address from company where lower(name) in (%s)", qmarks),
           params = tolower(df$names))
```

This takes advantage of three things:

- the SQL `IN` operator, which takes a list (vector in R) of values and conditions on "set membership";
- optimized queries; if you subsequently run this query again (with three arguments), then it will reuse the query. (Granted, if you run with other than three companies, then it will have to reoptimize, so this is limited gain);
- no need to deal with quoting/escaping your data values; for instance, if it is feasible that your company names might include single or double quotes (perhaps typos on user-entry), then adding the value to the query itself is either going to cause the query to fail, or you will have to jump through some hoops to ensure that all quotes are escaped properly for the DBMS to see it as the correct strings.